Why is this extension Galois?
I'm reading a proof of the FTA (taken in the book Algebra : Chapter 0 by Paolo Aluffi) and I'm having a hard time understanding the beginning :
"Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ be a nonconstant polynomial; we have to prove that $f(x)$
has roots in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $F$ be a splitting field for $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$; embed $F$ in an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$, and consider the extension
$$\mathbb{R} \subseteq F(i)$$
This extension is Galois: it is the splitting field of the square-free part of $f(x)(x^2 +
1)$."
Why is this true ? Also, did the author meant that $f(x)$ is in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ instead of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ ? Is there something I'm missing ?
Thank you for reading

You should cite your sources. Is this a textbook? A handout? Course notes? Who is "the author"?

Maybe they intended to write $f(x)\overline{f}(x)(x^2+1)$

@ArturoMagidin Corrected

Thank you. You do not want just a real polynomial, because that would not establish the FTA. But the reference ot a "square part" suggests that the author meant to consider the splitting field of $f(x)\overline{f(x)}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

@ArturoMagidin Well he does say I cite "Note that if $f(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{C}$, then neither does $f(x) \overline{f(x)} \in \mathbb{R}[x]$; that is, we may assume that $f(x)$ has real coefficients." I think that you are right

I checked in the book. A few lines before, they had replaced $f(x)$ with $f(x)\overline{f(x)}$

@ameg That seems to be the case. Thank you

Yes, you want the conjugate polynomial as a factor to force it into $\Bbb{R}[x]$. Using the factor $x^2+1$ also simplifies the argument a bit. Can do without, (discussed here) but the argument is a lot cleaner with that extra factor in there.
